# how check if tinymce editor is empty and forced_root_block option is set as div

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, html-editor

How can I check if tinymce has empty content? I'm testing it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jjw2U/

Tinymce editor doesn't return me a empty string because it set by default a empty tag

```
 <div>&nbsp;</div>
```

It put empty div row because I set forced_root_block option as 'div', but I don't want change forced_root_block.

I try with regex

```
    editorContent.replace("/(<div>&nbsp;</div>)+/gi"," "); 
    editorContent = editorContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
```

but It doesn' work. I wrong regex?

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Just add that to your test:

```
if (editorContent == '' || editorContent == null || editorContent == '<div>&nbsp;</div>')
```

It's not strictly speaking empty content, but it indicates the user hasn't made any meaningful changes to the textarea, which is I assume what you want to know.

Comment: It doesn't work because if user press enter different times tinymce put more <div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>

Comment: So what you want is to trim whitespace, whether literal or html entities, get rid of empty divs, and then check if the textarea is empty?

Comment: I'm trying     editorContent = editorContent.replace("/(<div>&nbsp;</div>)+/gi"," ");
    editorContent = editorContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,""); but it doesn't work. Maybe I wrong regex

Comment: And is that working? You should break the problem down into its separate components and deal with them individually.